# Is the surface of a metal less dense than the bulk?

Tags: surface-tension, metals

How is the density of the first few atomic layers of a metal compared to the bulk material?

Comment: Why does the lack of neighbours change their position? Density is how many atoms (how much mass) you have per volume.

Comment: the positions will definitely change since the surface-atoms will try to compensate for their unsaturated bonds (their potential energy will be quite different). I'm not sure in wich way this happens though...

Comment: Are you talking about atomic density or overall material density?

Comment: where's the difference? mass density is popto atomic density

Comment: Macroscopic effects are different than microscopic.

Comment: The wikipedia article on Surface Reconstruction would be the place to start. Note that your intuition needs calibration - without bonds for the outermost atoms, they generally want to move towards the bonds that they have, resulting in a slightly smaller spacing of the first plane(s). However, changes in the surface structure may result in something different.

Comment: that's right. actually the surface atoms should move towards the bulk...but as I found, this is not that easy to answer at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems this can not be answered in general since there are a bunch of different things which can happen, these are just some of them:

[image: a) deformation, b) and c)superstructure formation, d)facette layers e)incomplete layer]

a) deformation, b) and c)superstructure formation, d)facette layers  e)incomplete layer
It seems to be not that easy at all (source=[enter link description here](http://th.fhi-berlin.mpg.de/th/publications/Michaelides_Scheffler_Chapter_Submission.pdf):

> "The physical basis of the model is the Smoluchowski smoothing of the
>   electron charge density at the surface. When a crystal is cut to form
>   a surface, the electrons rearrange in order to reduce the
>   charge-density corrugations and by this way their kinetic energy. This
>   leads to a motion of the electrons left on top of the surface atoms
>   downward to the crystal resulting in an electrostatic attraction of
>   the top layer ions toward the rest of the crystal ....
>
> he model as outlined above, however, is not as general as one might be
>   lead to expect,and not as widely applicable as it is often said to be.
>   In particular the closest packed hexagonal surfaces of the fcc and hcp
>   metals often undergo an “anomalous” expansion of the first to second
>   layer distance relative to the bulk interlayer spacing"

[image]

And some measured/caluclated (DFT) values for interlayer spacings:
[image]

Comment: While those are some of the things that happen, this does not answer the question on how the near-surface density changes.

Comment: The edit makes it a nice answer. Good job.